# Correct way to enable TRIM on recent Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: ssd, trim

It used to be that properly enabling TRIM for SSDs on Linux involved two steps:

1. Running `fstrim` once, to take care of all the "untrimmed" blocks to date, then
2. Setting the `discard` flag in *fstab* (so the trimming would continue).

I'm a little behind the times. Now I'm seeing things about an [*fstrim.timer* service](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=292795) that is included in newer Linux distributions, and I'm seeing conflicting information about which combination of *fstrim.timer*, `fstrim`, and `discard` to use.

My question is, on modern Linuxes (modern at the time of this writing), what's the preferred way to enable TRIM on an SSD? Is it just to enable *fstrim.timer* and let it do its thing? Is the usage of the `discard` flag no longer necessary?

If it matters I'm specifically interested in Ubuntu >= 22 (Jammy) and Debian >= 10 (Buster).

Comment: Discard has not been recommended for years. Back then fstrim as cron job became standard. `tail -n1 /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` But I do not now have that file as systemd controls it. `systemctl status fstrim.timer`  Very old question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim#19480

Comment: Been using discard for as long as I remember myself without issues. There have been drives which misbehaved in the presence of the option but those were rare.